# Personality trait in which the person's style is evident in all they do?

Tags: single-word-requests

What is the term for the personality trait in which the person's style is evident in (bleeds into) all they do? There may be, for example, a particular style of handwriting, decoration, dress, driving, fighting, and countless others, that readily identifies that person.

Comment: You want a name for the trait (rather than an adjective)? Do you have a reason for thinking there would be such a name?

Comment: @chaslyfromUK Yes. I read it in a personality model article online and have never seen it since.

Comment: I think that maybe the following is the best place to ask. http://cogsci.stackexchange.com/search?q=trait

Comment: Possibly **eccentric**: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eccentricity_%28behavior%29

Answer (score 3):

**hallmark** (*noun*):

a typical characteristic or feature of a person or thing

> '*Simplicity is a hallmark of this design.*'

Source: [CDO](http://dictionary.cambridge.org)

**signature** (*noun*):

> a distinctive mark, characteristic, etc, that identifies a person or thing (3a)

Source: [Collins](http://www.collinsdictionary.com)

Answer (score 1):

For a comprehensive list of personality traits see

http://www.emotionalcompetency.com/adjectives.htm

A trait that indicates a person's style is stamped into everything they do is **consistent**:

> **consistent**
>
> *adjective*
>
> (Of a person, behavior, or process) unchanging in achievement or
>   effect over a period of time:
>   *manufacturing processes require a consistent approach*
> <sub>[ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/consistent)</sub>

Another possibility (though not on that list)

> **congruent**
>
> *adjective*
>
> In agreement or harmony
> <sub>[ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/congruent)</sub>

Answer (score 0):

Well, it's not specific to personality, but referring to a trait as "[pervasive](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/pervasive)" would probably do the trick.

> adjective
>
> 1. spread throughout: "The corruption is so pervasive that it is accepted as the way to do business."

You might also say that something is [characteristic](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/characteristic?s=t) of that person.

> adjective
>
> 1. Also, characteristical. pertaining to, constituting, or indicating the character or peculiar quality of a person or thing; typical; distinctive
>
> noun
>
> 2. a distinguishing feature or quality

While these may not be the exact words you're looking for, looking up synonyms for the above in any well-written thesaurus should yield a goldmine of useful facsimiles.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest [**"mark"**](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Mark) (6a)

> Good manners are the mark of a civilized person.

- He leaves his mark in every sculpture.  No sooner do you look at it, than you realize whose work it is.
- that kind of handwriting is her mark.

Depending on context, **"typical of"** may also fit.

> - "typical" - (adj)  Exhibiting the qualities, traits, or characteristics that identify a kind, class, group, or category: a typical suburban community. [TFD](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/typical)

Answer (score 0):

When someone's character is imbibed in his works, we generally use the terms "MARK"," IMPRINT" etc. and qualify such terms with such attributes as indelible/unmistakable / embedded or other befitting terms. We may use the term "CHARACTERISTICS" to describe one's peculiar traits.

• Whether he was writing novels or law-books, his characteristics prevailed.

However, it seems to me that if the person is famous an adjective from the proper noun can do the trick as in "Shakespearean", " Horatian ", " Platonic " and so on.